# While adding multiple web user control, an error occurs "only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page"

Tags: asp.net, exception, webforms, controls, scriptmanager

I have created a user control "Calendar" of ajax date extender along with a text box for taking the date. Now im trying to create this control dynamically for all the rows populating in my table. Its gives the following error :-
Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page.

here's the code :-

```
tc = new TableCell();
            tc.Style["width"] = "15%";
            Calendar1 = (ASP.Calendar)LoadControl("../Calendar.ascx");
            Calendar1.ID = "tbDate" + Convert.ToString(_id);
            tc.Controls.Add(Calendar1);
            tr.Cells.Add(tc);
            tc.Dispose();
            tc = null;
```

And i've declared a global variable :- public ASP.Calendar Calendar1;

Thanks in advance for ur suggestions.

Comment: remove from the calendar.ascx the extra ScriptManager

Comment: Please show code samples of your calendar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the ScriptManagerProxy component inside your web usercontrol instead of a full-blown ScriptManager. The ScriptManagerProxy was created just for this kind of use that you want.

"Enables nested components such as content pages and user controls to add script and service references to pages when a ScriptManager control is already defined in a parent element." - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanagerproxy.aspx

So basically make sure you use a ScriptManager on the calling page itself and use the ScriptManagerProxy component inside your Calendar.ascx web user control.

If your design don't really allow for that, how about creating a second version of Calendar.ascx only to be used as a nested control?

Answer (score 0):

You have included the script manager more than once in your page, possibly in the user control itself.